# Converting correctly Byte array to long C#

Tags: c#, byte, data-conversion

I would like to convert a byte array (byte[]) to a long in C#. I have already been able to research this and this thread is NOT a duplicate. Indeed, I need the conversion to be BigEndian which is done this way in Java:

```java
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(digest);
Long bufLong = buf.getLong(12); // int parameter = start index;
```

For exemple, here is a Java / C# convertion comparaison.
Java:

```java
public static void testLong()
    {
        byte[] testLong = new byte[]{
                (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0xe0, (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0xff,
                (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0xc3,
                (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xc2,
        };

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(testLong);

        for (int i = 0; i < (testLong.length - 8); i++) {
            System.out.println("i[" + i + "]: " + byteBuffer.getLong(i));
        }
    }
```

C#:

```cs
 public static void TestLong()
        {
            byte[] testLong = new byte[]{
                    (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0xe0, (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0xff,
                    (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0xc3,
                    (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xc2,
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < (testLong.Length - 8); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"I[{i}] : {BitConverter.ToInt64(testLong, i)}");
            }

            Array.Reverse(testLong);
            Console.WriteLine("Reversing the array ...");

            for (int i = 0; i < (testLong.Length - 8); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"I[{i}] : {BitConverter.ToInt64(testLong, i)}");
            }
        }
```

Java Output (Correct one):

```
i[0]: -5989710487062790209
i[1]: -2286126570181509242
i[2]: 5047408392239285955
i[3]: 864463253588591535
i[4]: -58335965835186188
i[5]: 3512736819901887595
i[6]: -4629833716884804610
```

C# Output (Incorrect):

```
I[0] : -4629928019949592404
I[1] : -8737054534917208352
I[2] : -4357584761552696506
I[3] : -5781629338509050101
I[4] : -815218024020758273
I[5] : 7779035710689886000
I[6] : -113728329830973505

Reversing the array ...

I[0] : -4645810805098676542
I[1] : -4629833716884804610
I[2] : 3512736819901887595
I[3] : -58335965835186188
I[4] : 864463253588591535
I[5] : 5047408392239285955
I[6] : -2286126570181509242
```

Note that i test to reverse the array because Java is BigEndian and C# is LittleEndian (Probably also the source of my problem but idk)

As you can see the convertion is not good.

I also tried to use a ByteBuffer port in C# without sucess: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/net/FlatBuffers/ByteBuffer.cs

If someone can help me with this problem, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: you know that 64 bit integer is 8 bytes long? not 15,  not 12 ... you need to revers 8 bytes not whole array

Comment: `BitConverter.ToInt64(testLong.Skip(i).Take(8).Reverse().ToArray(), 0)`

Comment: Are you sure this is doing what you want?  `byteBuffer.getLong(i)` in Java will advance through the byte buffer *one byte at a time.*  Meaning, each long value will be using the lowest three bytes from the previous long value.  15 bytes is only large enough to hold one long value (plus seven extra bytes).

Comment: @Selvin that is a very expensive way to approach this; `BinaryPrimitives` is the go-to here.

Comment: @MarcGravell I never claimed that it's the best way ... it just explains what he did wrong ... moreover without additional libraries there is no `BinaryPrimitives`  in plain old framework 4.x ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# is not *any* endian - in that unless you cheat and look under the covers: endianness is not a factor you see; .NET in general, and `BitConverter` in particular, are CPU-endian; and presumably your CPU is little-endian.

So: don't use that! `BinaryPrimitives` offers explicit-endian APIs; use the ones that are correct for your scenario.

Note: when reversing data for endianness reasons, you'd only reverse *that segment*, not the entire payload - which is why your `Reverse` attempt failed.

```cs
using System;
using System.Buffers.Binary;

ReadOnlySpan<byte> testLong = new byte[]{
    0xac, 0xe0, 0x46, 0x0b, 0xff,
    0x30, 0xbf, 0xbf, 0x86, 0xc3,
    0xaf, 0xf4, 0x6b, 0xfe, 0xc2,
};

for (int i = 0; i < (testLong.Length - 8); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"I[{i}] : {BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt64BigEndian(testLong.Slice(i))}");
}
```

Comment: I would write the output with `:x16` formatting also so you can tell it's working correctly by inspection `{BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt64BigEndian(testLong.Slice(i)):x16}`

Comment: Excellent answer ! Thanks a lot, the System.Memory operations was what i needed.